# Lua: fails to get field after loading a second string;

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

Good afternoon,
I am working on a LUA/C++ application, from which i need lua to be able to call other lua code recursively, e.g: C++ calls lua function, lua function calls another lua function from another string that is loaded using a registered C function that runs at the start of the first lua function;

here are the steps i am following:

```
    lua_State* state = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(state);
    lua_register(state, "secondLua", secondLua);
    lua_getfield( _luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "init" );
    lua_pcall( _luaState, 0, 0, 0 );

    int secondLua(lua_State* state){
    char* myString[128] = "function init2()\n io.write(\"hello\")\n end";
    luaL_loadstring(pLuaState, myString);
    lua_getfield(pLuaState,LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "init2"); // function init2 declared on myString
    lua_pcall(pLuaState, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
//getting "attempt to call a nil value" here

    return 0;  
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, and second, i would like to know if there is a way i can name the second function "init" as well as the first one;

PS: I am using C++14 and lua 5.1 on LUAJIT, and i cant use lua's dofile;

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem but have you considered using a wrapper library such as [sol](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[c]`?

Comment: @KemyLand Because this is C API for Lua I guess.

Comment: @Jakuje: The OP is talking about C++ anyways, not C.

Comment: This compiles? That second call to `lua_getfield` is missing an argument.

Comment: The second call of `pcall` expects **0** input arguments, so just loads the function from stack top. On top is the result of `lua_getfield(pLuaState, "init2");` BUT `init2` was never defined because your `mystring` was just loaded, never executed to load this function into the environment!

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the second argument, this is adapted code, since i cannot share the source...:/ ps: i corrected the argument...

Comment: Youka, i fixed my code and "pcall"ed it before getting the field and then "pcall"ed it once more with the field set, worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

lua_loadstring() compiles supplied source and puts Lua chunk on stack. It won't execute it though, so init2() still not defined when you expect that.
Replace lua_loadstring() with luaL_dostring() to actually run that chunk and define new lua functions. Or call lua_pcall() right after lua_loadstring(). Actually, luaL_dostring() does exactly that - lua_loadstring() followed by lua_pcall().